# How to fetch data as .csv file from client with node.js application

Tags: javascript, node.js, csv, heroku, server

i have written a game in javascript with the p5.js library. Now i want to host the game on a server to conduct a survey on a service like amazon turk. Ideally the clients recieve a URL to the game and play it while in-game actions are tracked and stored in node.js or on the server and exported as a .csv file once they are done playing. After they finish the game the csv. file should be sent automatically to a location that i can then access. I have zero experience in server hosting or similar topics.

So a couple questions arise:

1. Is a hosting service like Heroku suitable for hosting the game?
2. Do i need to use node.js to make this happen?
3. Which of those two would extract the data and store it to a csv? And where is the file     stored?
4. How do i get or access the csv. after?
5. Any alternative takes to solve the problem?

Thanks alot in advance!

- github repository: https://github.com/luuuucaaa/schaeffers-charade
- game on github pages: https://luuuucaaa.github.io/schaeffers-charade/

Comment: First of all, the app is on github pages already, and I don't see the point why you want it to hosted on other servers. Any additional workflows (the survery) can be written within your p5 script (sth like posting data to amazon S3 or actual RDS) .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I were you, I would do it like below:

**Host**
Since your project is basically a html & JavaScript static contents,
AWS S3's [static hosting](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/userguide/HostingWebsiteOnS3Setup.html) would be sufficient (Also, the current git hub pages is another option if you just want to host it).

Hosting on node.js environment is also available using `webpack` serving, but it requires additional works. (but if you require other npm packages to generate .csv file, you need webpack anyway to bundle js file and attach it to html)

**Data Storing**
Two ways are considerable,
the first is to store it on the filesystem. Generate .csv via JS script within your app, and save it where the app is hosted (if you go with s3, you can access it afterwards, but I'm not sure if it can write objects by script)

The second is to post the data to another API endpoint. (for example building an API Gateway on AWS that triggers Lambda, which stores it on S3)

It's merely an example and I don't know exactly what you want to achieve, but take it into considerations. Good luck. Cool game BTW.

Comment: thanks a lot, sounds doable. i will give it a try!